# pypy heapq c implementation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pypy

Why is the c module for heapq not available to pypy, and what can I do to make it available?

i.e.

```
Python 2.7.13 (c5b147d52043, Jan 01 2018, 23:13:26)
[PyPy 5.11.0-alpha0 with GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``"translation toolchain" =
"RPyther"?  to write inteRPythers in''
>>>> import heapq
py version
```

when i modify the source:

```
try:
    from _heapq import *
    print "c version"
except ImportError:
    print "py version"
    pass
```

yet cpython:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Nov 24 2017, 17:33:09) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import heapq
c version
>>> exit()
```

thanks,

Chris

Comment: Why do you want to use that?

Comment: PyPy doesn't support the full Python C API.  But I would expect it to run the Python code quickly.  Why do you want the C version?

Comment: It does run the python code quickly, I want the c version to compare them, I just expected it to be there. I am comparing a bunch of priority queue type data structures.

Comment: You'll have to measure the C version using CPython, not PyPy.

Comment: You can take the C version from the source code of CPython, extract it as a regular C module (which means just adding a setup.py), and manually compile it with PyPy.  I am sure that the result would be much slower, though, because of the overhead of constantly calling the C code through the emulated CPython API.  That would be the case for any C extension that implements a data structure with not much on top.